# Regular expression to match text within quotes

Tags: regular-expressions

I have a text like this:

```
''Lorem ipsum'' dolor ''sit amet, '' consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

What I want is to get the *sit amet* correctly wrapped around with `''`, like this:

```
''Lorem ipsum'' dolor ''sit amet'', consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

The problem is that my regular expression selects this:

```
''Lorem ipsum'' dolor ''sit amet, ''
```

instead of just this:

```
''sit amet, ''
```

and, if that is the case, the text selected is not the text I want to correct. Any help?

### EDIT

Sorry, yes, indeed I didn't provided any regexp. The thing is I'm using [visual-regexp](https://github.com/benma/visual-regexp.el) and [visual-regexp-steroids](https://github.com/benma/visual-regexp-steroids.el/), in other words I'm using the regular expression engine(?) that comes with Python. That's why I didn't provided any.

The regexp `''([^']+), ''` works ok (I still have to check the entire 11MB of text) as suggested by mbork.

Comment: What's your failing regex?

Comment: You didn't help us a lot by not providing your regex.  But: is this what you are looking for: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexps.html#index-non_002dgreedy-regexp-matching-890 ?

Comment: Ah.  If it's something like `''\(.+\), ''`, then non-greedy operators won't help apparently.  Maybe try something like `''\([^']+\), ''`?

Comment: @mbork This will fail for `''sit 'amet, ''`, won't it?

Comment: Yes it will, of course.  But it might be true that the OP doesn't have any ticks in his text, no?  In general: I'm not sure regexen are really the best way to do what the OP wants to do.  Another idea would be first to convert all `''` sequences to some *single* character not appearing anywhere in the buffer, then do the transformation, and then convert back.  Or just write some Elisp to do what the OP needs.  Currently, the problem is underspecified anyway.

Comment: Also, I'd consider (non-regex) replacing `, ''` with `'',`, possibly interactively (in case one gets false positives).

Comment: `''([^']+), ''` will not work for the text like: `''it's a boy, ''`.  Also, I'd imagine that the problem with the comma hints at other possible problems with punctuation. Can you elaborate more on the nature of the task? Perhaps, if you could get the original text without quotes inserted it would be easier to insert them properly than to fix it post factum?

Comment: wvxvw, the text is in spanish, and we don't use `'` that much, so that is not actually a problem. The document is marked with mediawiki's markup I get by exporting the original odt file to mediawiki markup.

There are other cases though, like `''lorem ipsum ''` (note the white space) where the used regexp without the `,` selects entires paragraphs

Comment: I'm pretty confused by this question. It sounds like either (a) this is a Python question (and hence entirely off-topic for emacs.se); or (b) you're trying to build an elisp regexp using a tool for making Python regexps (instead of something appropriate, such as `M-x re-builder`). Either way, something seems wrong here. Can you please clarify?

Comment: non of the above.

Comment: Oh I see! Sorry, my fault for not following the visual-regexp* links you'd provided. I didn't realise anything like that existed, and made a bad assumption.

Comment: That said, the question still seems like "how do I write a *python* regexp to match X", with the Emacs integration being purely incidental?

Comment: not at all, I can still use any regex built for Emacs, if I talk here about regex built for Python `re` is for convenience to me since is the only syntax I domain.

Answer (score 4):

Non-greedy `*?` or `+?` postfix operators are what I usually use in these situations. In Emacs read syntax:

```
"''\\(.*?\\)''"
```

will match anything enclosed in `''` which does not *contain* `''` (because if it contained it, there would be a shorter (less-greedy) match).

n.b.: `.` does not match newlines in Emacs regexps. To also allow for newlines between the quotes, you could use:

```
"''\\(\\(?:.\\|\n\\)*?\\)''"
```

In either case, `\1` is grouping the contents between the `''` quotes.

Answer (score 0):

A classical trick is to use `(re-search-forward "''\\([^']\\|'[^']\\)+, ''")`. The group means "no tick, or only one".

Answer (score -1):

The solution given by [mbork](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5849/regular-expression-to-match-text-within-quotes#comment8827_5849) worked fine. I had other case like `''sit amet ''` where using `\([^']+\)` wasn't a good idea. I decided then to build this regexp `'+(\w+) '+` (using the Python re module through *visual-regexp-steroids*, an Emacs extension) and my text is almost done!